# SSL certificate testing

Tags: testing, ssl

Is it possible to test a website under HTTPS during the development phase, i.e. without actually purchasing an SSL certificate?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can either use self-signed certificates or create your own CA. OpenSSL comes with a test script for doing this (`CA.pl`, which even has its own man page). You would then have to import that test CA certificate into your test clients.

Comment: If you need help generating a self-signed certificate, use one of these tutorials: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate.html You could also get a free SSL certificate from a CA like StartCom.

Answer (score 1):

For windows developer, 
If you use IIS 7, you can use self-signed certificates easily. Try [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx).
If your dev environment is IIS 6, then you can use [IIS 6.0 resource kit with this post](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2005/08/26/ssl-and-development/).

Answer (score 0):

```
openssl x509 -text -noout
```

You can download and config openssl. Generate self sign cert. Configure in your server. check your cert details using above cmd:-